# PayPal Recurring Payments - Are Billing Plans meant to have multiple Billing Agreements?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

Let's say I have a service where a user can subscribe for:

- $10/Month
- $25/Month
- $50/Year

Am I correct that to set this up properly with PayPal's API, I should:

1. Create three `Billing Plans` - one `Billing Plan` for each payment tier
2. Activate each `Billing Plan`
3. When a customer subscribes, they create a `Billing Agreement` under one of the preexisting `Billing Plans` and go through the authorization process? Thus, multiple customers would have agreements under say the $10/Month `Billing Plan`?

I'm further confused because, astonishingly, there is no way to use the API to list all of the `Agreements`: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/5

Answer (score 2):

> When a customer subscribes, they create a Billing Agreement under one of the preexisting Billing Plans and go through the authorization process? Thus, multiple customers would have agreements under say the $10/Month Billing Plan?

Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no API to list all of the agreements, so you could create a billing plan every time a customer subscribes. Then you would be able to list all of the billing plans you created.

> GET /v1/payments/billing-plans

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/#billing-plans_list